# Microsoft.Bot.Sample.QnABot - Authenticating Error

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I'm trying to use the downloaded src project from "Download source code" from Azure portal but it is unable to authenticate.

> Failed authenticating incoming request:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols, Version=2.1.4.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.\r\nFile name:
>   'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols, Version=2.1.4.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Connector.JwtTokenExtractor..ctor(TokenValidationParameters
>   tokenValidationParameters, String metadataUrl, String[]
>   allowedSigningAlgorithms, EndorsementsValidator validator)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Connector.BotAuthenticator.GetTokenExtractor(TokenValidationParameters
>   parameters, String openIdConfigurationUrl, EndorsementsValidator
>   validator)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Connector.BotAuthenticator.d__14.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Connector.BotAuthenticator.d__10.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.BotAuthentication.

```
<packages>
  <package id="Autofac" version="3.5.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Chronic.Signed" version="0.3.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB" version="1.22.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bot.Builder" version="3.15.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure" version="3.15.2.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices" version="1.1.7" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bot.Builder.History" version="3.15.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bot.Connector" version="3.15.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions" version="1.0.4.403061554" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols" version="2.1.4" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" version="2.1.4" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net46" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" version="2.3.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" version="3.2.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="System.Dynamic.Runtime" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Queryable" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="System.Net.Requests" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="8.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
</packages>
```

Comment: You can try to downgrade/upgrade the package and check if other version(s) of package could work.

Answer (score 0):

try to download from GitHub, usually it works: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples

Comment: There does not seem to be a example QnA project,

Comment: Hi Arran! The QnA maker sample is at https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/QnAMaker